# Multiple sigs for method

Tags: sorbet

I'm trying to add types for the `promise.rb` gem. Specifically, I'm aiming to create a half-decent definition for the `Promise.all` static method.

Essentially, it is a flatmap over an array that goes from `[Promise[A], Promise[B]]` to `Promise[[A, B]]`.

I've got a working signature for *one* item, and I'd like to hard-code for a few different amounts (say, up to 10), given that I don't think there is a good way to do it automatically.

I can't, as far as I can tell, just put a bunch of sigs above the method definition, which I already tried.

The sig looks like this (in the rbi - no implementation):

```rb
  sig do
    type_parameters(:A)
      .params(enum: [
        Promise[T.type_parameter(:A)], 
      ])
      .returns(Promise[[
        T.type_parameter(:A),
      ]])
  end
  def self.all(enum); end
```

for two items, it would look like this:

```rb
  sig do
    type_parameters(:A, :B)
      .params(enum: [
        Promise[T.type_parameter(:A)], 
        Promise[T.type_parameter(:B)],
      ])
      .returns(Promise[[
        T.type_parameter(:A),
        T.type_parameter(:B),
      ]])
  end
  def self.all(enum); end
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the variadic type in the ActiveRecord RBI file might be a good reference: https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet-typed/blob/0d1d348330ff86381a6b73110954aa75ad730bc8/lib/activerecord/all/activerecord.rbi#L3

Comment: Unfortunately, Sorbet only support multi-sigged methods in the core RBI files. It doesn't allow them anywhere else :/ Getting a particularly accurate signature for this method probably isn't really possible.

Comment: @ConnorShea seems like a weird restriction to have, I think.